# Dynamic y axis for charts

Tags: ios, swift, logic, ios-charts, computation

I am integrating the [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/v2.3.0). I want to layout the `y-axis of graph dynamically` on the basis of json response. For example:- if `json` contains 50 values, then I will draw 10(50/5)+5 = `15` yaxis values. These 15 values must contains the minimum and maximum json value. the remaining 13 values must have fixed-step between them. I write multiple logic and fail to deliver the right results. I am open to ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the least common multiple and use this as a basis to pick out the right values. I found some nice work here: [Ray Wenderlich Algorithms](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/GCD)

In your above example you will wind up with a `commonMultiple = 150`. `originalCount` is the number of values you had to begin with (50).

Then it would be something like this I guess. `values` is an array of values created from your json.

```
var multipliedValues = [Int]()
for value in values {
    multipliedValues += [Int](repeating: value, count: commonMultiple/originalCount)
}
```

Then you are ready to pick out a subset of values:

```
let numberOfSteps = (originalCount/5)+5
var yValues = [Int]()
for n in 0..<numberOfSteps{
    let index = n*commonMultiple/numberOfSteps
    yValues.append(multipliedValues[index])
}
```

Then the final tricky part is to insert the lowest and highest values. Something like this perhaps:

```
let minValue = values.sorted().first!
if !yValues.contains(minValue) {
    let minIndex = multipliedValues.index(of: minValue)! / (commonMultiple/numberOfSteps)
    yValues[minIndex] = minValue
}
let maxValue = values.sorted().last!
if !yValues.contains(maxValue) {
    let maxIndex = multipliedValues.index(of: maxValue)! / (commonMultiple/numberOfSteps)
    yValues[maxIndex] = maxValue
}
```